# MySQL declare variable in trigger error

Tags: mysql, triggers

Anybody know what's wrong with my trigger declaration?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sch_trigger_curriculum_subject_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON  
`sch_curriculum_subject` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   DECLARE curriculum_code VARCHAR(50);        
   SET curriculum_code = SELECT code FROM sch_curriculum WHERE id=NEW.id;
   SET NEW.`code_name` = CONCAT(curriculum_code,' - ', NEW.code,' - (',NEW.name,')');
END;
```

The error: SQL Error(1064): You have error in you SQL syntax ..... near '' at line 4.

According to error message, there is something wrong with my curriculum_code declaration. But I cant find out what's wrong.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
already solved, the problem is on delimiter, here is the working one

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `sch_trigger_curriculum_subject_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON  
`sch_curriculum_subject` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE curriculum_code VARCHAR(50);        
  SET curriculum_code = (SELECT code FROM sch_curriculum WHERE id=NEW.id);
  SET NEW.`code_name` = CONCAT(curriculum_code,' - ', NEW.code,' - (',NEW.name,')');
END$$
```

Comment: Is curriculum_code returns multiple rows ?

Comment: @Tornike, no it is not. The problem is on delimiter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure multiple values are not returned from the `SELECT`.

Try:

```
SET curriculum_code = (SELECT code FROM sch_curriculum WHERE id=NEW.id LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Yeah. This is one of the error reason. I'll accept your answer later. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a `SELECT` statement to a variable in that fashion.  At very least you should place the `SELECT` statement within parentheses to execute it as a subquery, but better yet:

```
SELECT code FROM sch_curriculum WHERE id = NEW.id INTO curriculum_code;
```

Be careful that the query does not return multiple records (one assumes that there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `id` column, so this probably isn't an issue).

Comment: thx for your suggestion. I can make sure that the query is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply `SET curriculum_code = some_SQL`. I suspect you mean `SELECT ... INTO curriculum_code`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I think I've found the problem